# R Left join using tidyverse/dplyr drops data from df 2

Tags: r

I have been searching and searching and have to resolved to post! I'm still pretty new to R.

I have 2 data frames. The large one is HEAT and the small one is EE.

I have manage to do a left join to get EE matched up with HEAT.

```
df(HEAT)
Date Time.       EVENT.    Person.    PersonID
DTgroup1.         X.        Code.       Code
DTgroup2.         X         Code.       Code
DTgroup3.         Y.        Code.       Code
....
```

Then there is:

```
df(EE)
Person ID.       Type.      var 3.     var 4    var 5
```

here is the merge that I used:

```
merge <- left_join(HEAT, EE)
```

I have managed to merge the two data frames but I loose all the data in `df(EE)` except for the `PersonID` that it share with `df(HEAT)`.

Does anyone have any advice about what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: How do you expect your output to be? What do you join on? `left_join` will try to find a match for all rows of HEAT inside EE. If there is a match it will be joined otherwise it will produce NAs. It doesn't care about EE rows that doesn't match with HEAT. You wanted a `full_join` maybe?

Comment: so does that mean that I need to do a full_join on PersonID? to keep the rest of the data?

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep all data apart from the cases where you have a match you need a `full_join`. If you care more about EE data you can do a `right_join(HEAT, EE)` or `left_join(EE, HEAT)`. There are some nice links with info in the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

A left join will keep all rows on the left side, in your case HEAT, and include data where there is a match on the right hand side.

An inner join, would only return records where there is a valid join on both sides, in your case, one record would be returned.

See [What is the difference between “INNER JOIN” and “OUTER JOIN”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you want a

```
merge <- full_join(HEAT, EE)
```

Here is a nice Cheat sheet page http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html
And here a super nice graphics http://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html